# Basic structure of a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, factorial

I am trying to write a MATLAB function that accepts non-integer, n, and then returns the factorial of it, n!. I am supposed to use a for loop. I tried with

"for n >= 0"

but this did not work. Is there a way how I can fix this?

I wrote this code over here but this doesn't give me the correct answer..

```
    function fact = fac(n);
    for fact = n
        if n >=0
            factorial(n)
            disp(n)
        elseif n < 0
            disp('Cannot take negative integers')
        break
        end
    end
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [read the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) *and* I would highly recommend doing a basic tutorial. The docs state

> ```
> for index = values
>     statements
> end
> ```

So your first idea of `for n >= 0` is completely wrong because a `for` doesn't allow for the `>`. That would be the way you would write a `while` loop.

Your next idea of `for fact = n` does fit the pattern of `for index = values`, however, your `values` is a single number, `n`, and so this loop will only have one single iteration which is obviously not what you want.

If you wanted to loop from `1` to `n` you need to create a vector, (i.e. the `values` from the docs) that contains all the numbers from `1` to `n`. In MATLAB you can do this easily like this: `values = 1:n`. Now you can call `for fact = values` and you will iterate all the way from `1` to `n`. However, it is very strange practice to use this intermediary variable `values`, I was just using it to illustrate what the docs are talking about. The correct standard syntax is

```
for fact = 1:n
```

Now, for a factorial (although technically you'll get the same thing), it is clearer to actually loop from `n` down to `1`. So we can do that by declaring a step size of `-1`:

```
for fact = n:-1:1
```

So now we can find the factorial like so:

```
function output = fac(n)
    output = n;
    for iter = n-1:-1:2 %// note there is really no need to go to 1 since multiplying by 1 doesn't change the value. Also start at n-1 since we initialized output to be n already
        output = output*iter;
    end
end
```

Calling the builtin `factorial` function inside your own function really defeats the purpose of this exercise. Lastly I see that you have added a little error check to make sure you don't get negative numbers, that is good however the check should not be inside the loop!

```
function output = fac(n)
    if n < 0
        error('Input n must be greater than zero'); %// I use error rather than disp here as it gives clearer feedback to the user
    else if n == 0
        output = 1;  %// by definition
    else
        output = n;
        for iter = n-1:-1:2 
            output = output*iter;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Dan! I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the point, what you are trying to do with "for". What I think, what you want to do is:

```
function fact = fac(n);
    if n >= 0
        n = floor(n);
        fact = factorial(n);
        disp(fact)
    elseif n < 0
        disp('Cannot take negative integers')
        return
    end
end
```

Depending on your preferences you can replace `floor`(round towards minus infinity) by `round`(round towards nearest integer) or `ceil`(round towards plus infinity). Any round operation is necessary to ensure `n` is an integer.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify if you question is about `for`-loops or about getting your function to work

Comment: Thank you for commenting on my post. This is my very first MATLAB project where I am supposed to write a function that accepts non-negative integer, (0<=k), and returns the factorial of the number by simply using a "for-loop". I am sorry for the confusion. Again thank you for taking your time.

Comment: Well just improve the solution from Dan with `floor`/`round`/`ceil` to get your function working with non-integer values